# Having an issue authenticating google sign in with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

So I'm trying different approaches to make authentication with flutter to work with no success.

Before posting the code it's important to say that I couldn't make the google services 4.3.3 work with any Gradle version so I have changed the versions to Gradle 3.2.1 and google services to 4.2.0 and I checked connectivity with firebase and it works. Plus, I added SHA1.

I can't track the error causing the application to fail and it's not the first post I have uploaded about it and I have searched online so many solutions with no success.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

---

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

main class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'ProfileScreen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Google Signin APP',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff9C58D2),
      ),
      home: GoogleSignApp(),
    );
  }
```

### }

```
class GoogleSignApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleSignAppState createState() => _GoogleSignAppState();
}

class _GoogleSignAppState extends State<GoogleSignApp> {

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googlSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async {

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
      content: new Text('Sign in'),
    ));

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googlSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    FirebaseUser userDetails = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)) as FirebaseUser;
    ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

    List<ProviderDetails> providerData = new List<ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details = new UserDetails(
      userDetails.providerId,
      userDetails.displayName,
      userDetails.photoUrl,
      userDetails.email,
      providerData,
    );
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new ProfileScreen(detailsUser: details),
      ),
    );
    return userDetails;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Image.network(
                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518050947974-4be8c7469f0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'
                  ,fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height:10.0),
                Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google,color: Color(0xffCE107C),),
                            SizedBox(width:10.0),
                            Text(
                              'Sign in with Google',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],),
                        onPressed: () => _signIn(context)
                            .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
                            .catchError((e) => print(e)),
                      ),
                    )
                ),

                Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebookF,color: Color(0xff4754de),),
                            SizedBox(width:10.0),
                            Text(
                              'Sign in with Facebook',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    )
                ),
                Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidEnvelope,color: Color(0xff4caf50),),
                            SizedBox(width:10.0),
                            Text(
                              'Sign in with Email',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ],),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),),
    );
  }
}



class UserDetails {
  final String providerDetails;
  final String userName;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String userEmail;
  final List<ProviderDetails> providerData;

  UserDetails(this.providerDetails,this.userName, this.photoUrl,this.userEmail, this.providerData);
}


class ProviderDetails {
  ProviderDetails(this.providerDetails);
  final String providerDetails;
```

### }

ProfileScreen class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';



class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserDetails detailsUser;

  ProfileScreen({Key key, @required this.detailsUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GoogleSignIn _gSignIn =  GoogleSignIn();

    return  Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text(detailsUser.userName),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt,
                size: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: (){
                _gSignIn.signOut();
                print('Signed out');
                Navigator.pop(context);

              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body:Center(child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:NetworkImage(detailsUser.photoUrl),
              radius: 50.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(height:10.0),
            Text(
              "Name : " + detailsUser.userName,
              style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(height:10.0),
            Text(
              "Email : " + detailsUser.userEmail,
              style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(height:10.0),
            Text(
              "Provider : " + detailsUser.providerDetails,
              style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black,fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),)
    );
  }
}
```

after the two suggestions this is the run log

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
I/zygote  ( 7873): Background concurrent copying GC freed 13033(968KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(228KB) LOS objects, 62% free, 907KB/2MB, paused 5.177ms total 65.168ms
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation( 7873): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6c85960: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa6c83c10)
I/zygote  ( 7873): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at android.content.Intent com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzh.zzc(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions) ((null):5)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at android.content.Intent com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent() ((null):20)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.signIn(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (GoogleSignInPlugin.java:291)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin.onMethodCall(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (GoogleSignInPlugin.java:77)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(java.nio.ByteBuffer, io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger$BinaryReply) (MethodChannel.java:222)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (DartMessenger.java:96)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (FlutterJNI.java:656)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:325)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:142)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
I/zygote  ( 7873): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86, /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at android.content.Intent com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzh.zzc(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions) ((null):5)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at android.content.Intent com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent() ((null):20)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.signIn(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (GoogleSignInPlugin.java:291)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin.onMethodCall(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result) (GoogleSignInPlugin.java:77)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(java.nio.ByteBuffer, io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger$BinaryReply) (MethodChannel.java:222)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (DartMessenger.java:96)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(java.lang.String, byte[], int) (FlutterJNI.java:656)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:325)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:142)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
I/zygote  ( 7873):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
I/zygote  ( 7873): 
E/flutter ( 7873): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/SignInHubActivity;
E/flutter ( 7873):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzh.zzc(Unknown Source:5)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(Unknown Source:20)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.signIn(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:291)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:77)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
E/flutter ( 7873): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity
E/flutter ( 7873):  at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/flutter ( 7873):  ... 14 more
E/flutter ( 7873): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;
E/flutter ( 7873):  ... 14 more
E/flutter ( 7873): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86, /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/flutter ( 7873):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/flutter ( 7873):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/flutter ( 7873):  ... 14 more
E/flutter ( 7873): 
F/flutter ( 7873): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
F/libc    ( 7873): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 7873 (ntication_demo2)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.0.0/OSR1.180418.019/5598391:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 7873, tid: 7873, name: ntication_demo2  >>> omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2 <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00001ec1  ecx 00001ec1  edx 00000006
    esi 00001ec1  edi bff981e8
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
    eip b49e3ac4  ebp bff98208  esp bff9819c  flags 00200296
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000ac4  [vdso:b49e3000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
    #01 pc 00075b3c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+28)
    #02 pc 0001f04e  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+110)
    #03 pc 01115f65  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #04 pc 0110443b  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #05 pc 01102202  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #06 pc 011622ad  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #07 pc 01114729  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #08 pc 01116ce8  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #09 pc 01116c2a  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #10 pc 0111d678  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #11 pc 0111d6a6  /data/app/omermichleviz.com.authentication_demo2-em0cledzfIMvQw6_BGX_Vg==/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x10fb000)
    #12 pc 000149b7  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android20SimpleLooperCallback11handleEventEiiPv+39)
    #13 pc 000157ec  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+988)
    #14 pc 00015386  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+118)
    #15 pc 000e4cbb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7androidL38android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxi+59)
    #16 pc 007b7df8  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5e9000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+136)
    #17 pc 00638d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
    #18 pc 00112b48  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+232)
    #19 pc 0032322f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+367)
    #20 pc 0031be11  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+817)
    #21 pc 0061f83b  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+523)
    #22 pc 00629a21  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14369)
    #23 pc 002f5f89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+537)
    #24 pc 002fdf0a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+234)
    #25 pc 0031bde5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+773)
    #26 pc 0061e1a1  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+881)
    #27 pc 00629921  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
    #28 pc 002f5f89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+537)
    #29 pc 002fdf0a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+234)
    #30 pc 0031bde5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+773)
    #31 pc 0061fb24  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+484)
    #32 pc 00629aa1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
    #33 pc 002f5f89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+537)
    #34 pc 002fddeb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+139)
    #35 pc 0060e56f  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1375)
    #36 pc 0063edad  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
    #37 pc 00638f22  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
    #38 pc 00112b92  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+306)
    #39 pc 00533065  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+101)
    #40 pc 005350f6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_j+1478)
    #41 pc 004a2450  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+80)
    #42 pc 0026dbd8  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x1df000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+168)
    #43 pc 00638d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
    #44 pc 00112b48  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+232)
    #45 pc 0032322f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+367)
    #46 pc 0031be11  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+817)
    #47 pc 0061e1a1  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+881)
    #48 pc 00629921  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
    #49 pc 002f5f89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+537)
    #50 pc 002fddeb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+139)
    #51 pc 0060e56f  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1375)
    #52 pc 0063edad  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
    #53 pc 01618453  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5e9000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2707)
    #54 pc 00638f22  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
    #55 pc 00112b92  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+306)
    #56 pc 00533065  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+101)
    #57 pc 00532d29  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDPc+441)
    #58 pc 004116d0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDPc+992)
    #59 pc 00152055  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDPcNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+3237)
    #60 pc 0013eb0b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDPc+75)
    #61 pc 000819be  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv20CallStaticVoidMethodEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz+62)
    #62 pc 00083e96  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+838)
    #63 pc 00001db3  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1603)
Lost connection to device.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
FirebaseUser userDetails = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)) as FirebaseUser;
```

to

```
FirebaseUser userDetails = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
```